# How to avoid dotfiles or dot directories in a http response

Tags: http, go, unsafe

How can I avoid sending files in a dot folder like `.git` or dot file like `.gitignore` in a http response?

I want to send a error if user request this kind of files.

Comment: you wrap the file server handler, check for the request uri, if it ends in anything undesirable, return an error, otherwise, execute the http file system handler.

Comment: Give me some code example

Answer (score 1):

Following is an example partial snippet. The code checks whether the requested file is `.gitignore`. You will need to adapt this to your code and to extend the `if` check to handle your specific needs.

```golang
...

func isPrivate(urlPath string) bool {
    for _, segment := range strings.Split(urlPath, "/") {
        if strings.HasPrefix(segment, ".") {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
...

func main() {
    originalHandler := http.FileServer(http.Dir(".")) // or I presume something similar

    http.Handle("/", http.HandlerFunc(func(resp http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        if isPrivate(req.URL.Path) {
            http.Error(resp, http.StatusText(http.StatusNotFound), http.StatusNotFound)
            return
        }

        originalHandler.ServeHTTP(resp, req)
    }))

    ...
}
```

Comment: This only detect .gitignore. But i something that can identity any .file or file in a dot folder

Comment: There is a problem. http.HandlerFunc is 
a type not a function. On type conversion it  accepts a function and return a HanerFunc which implement a Handler

Comment: @deepnum, yes, `HandlerFunc` accepts a function and converts it into an `http.Handler`. I had a mistake in the code, which is now corrected.

What the code does is that it registers a handler that checks (the `if` statement) whether the targeted resource is a `.gitignore` file. If it is, then a `NotFound` status code is returned and the request is no longer processed. Otherwise, the original http handler is called, which in your case I presume is an `http.FileServer`.

Comment: @deepnum, I have extended the code to show how you could detect a `.file` or file in dot dir. Now, I haven't tested it nor checked whether it compiles but you should be able to adapt the idea on your own.

Comment: 2nd argument of http.Handle accepts a handler interface and http.HandlerFunc implements http.Handler interface.

Comment: @deepnum, `http.HandlerFunc` implements the `http.Handler` interface, which is exactly what the second argument to [http.Handle](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#example_Handle) should be.

I tested the code locally, and it had a problem with the `isPrivate` function, which is now corrected. The http side of the code is working, however. Are you sure you didn't accidentally type `http.HandleFunc` instead of `http.HandlerFunc`?